# How do I set Fortify to display all of my JSP parsing errors?

Tags: jsp, parsing, fortify

We've recently finished an upgrade of our application to RAD 7.5, and have begun our Fortify process.  We've run into some trouble, namely concerning the .jsp files.

When I attempt to run a Fortify scan on the project, it comes back with a number of errors and warnings, most notably of two types:

> [error]: Failed to translate the following 3 jsps into analysis model. Please see the log file for any errors from the jsp parser and the user manual for hints on fixing those.

I have checked the documentation, but can find no mention of where Fortify keeps its log files.

I also have this error:

> [warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file [filename]: Parse error at line 211, column 10.  Encountered: Transactions

"Transactions" is not the only parsing error I encounter though.  I also encounter the following:

```
<, ;, of, &, /, of, of, &, "\n" (10) after : "#"
```

Most troubling is this last line, which suggests more errors that I am not able to see:

> [warning]: Some errors or warnings were suppressed.  To view all warnings and errors use the -show-build-warnings option:
>    sourceanalyzer -b [application name] -show-build-warnings

To summarize the jist of my question:

- Where can I find the log files/error logs for Fortify?
- How do I handle parsing errors in JSP files?
- How do I set Fortify to show all build warnings?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can better diagnose issues with Fortify:

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyBuildName -clean
sourceanalyzer -b MyBuildName -debug-verbose -logfile TranslateLog.txt <your translation args here>
sourceanalyzer -b MyBuildName -debug-verbose -logfile ScanLog.txt -scan -f MyBuild.fpr
```

Comment: I don't know where to put any of these.

Comment: No, I'm running it from Eclipse, or exporting my project and running it from the Fortify Tool.

Comment: You can set additional arguments by going to HP Fortify -> Options... -> Default Project Settings -> Advanced Options -> Use Additional SCA Arguments

Put -debug-verbose -logfile TranslateLog.txt in the Translate box and -debug-verbose -logfile ScanLog.txt in the Scan box.